# Matching performance with pattern from table column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, postgresql-performance

I have a query which looks like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE 'some_string' LIKE mytable.some_column || '%%'
```

How can I index `some_column` to improve this query performance?
Or is the a better way to filter this?

Comment: Please confirm: `'some_string' LIKE mytable.some_column || '%'`, not `mytable.some_column LIKE 'some_string%'`? If so, how long can your strings be (min/avg/max)? How many rows in the table, how many distinct strings? Also: Your Postgres version and table definition showing data type and constraints for relevant columns and the related indexes you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate searches for all prefixes for a given string:

```
WHERE 'some_string' LIKE mytable.some_column || '%'
```

If `%` has special meaning in your client, escape with another `%`. Else `'%%'` is just noise and can be replaced with `'%'`.

The most efficient solution should be a recursive CTE (or similar) that matches to every prefix exactly, starting with `some_column = left('some_string', 1)`, up to `some_column = left('some_string', length('some_string'))` (= `'some_string'`).

You only need a plain B-tree index on the column for this. Depending on details of your implementation, partial expression indexes might improve performance ...

Related:

- [Reverse pattern matching: find the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185093/3684)
- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43444/3684)
- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: I can provide the rCTE, but first clarify your question, please.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have enough to find out how to solve this. It seems its a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you intend to write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE mytable.some_column LIKE 'some_string%';
```

In other words, you want to find records where some column begins with `some_string` followed by anything, possibly nothing at all.

As far as I know, a regular B-tree index on `some_column` will be effective, to a point, in your query.  The reason is that Postgres can traverse the tree looking for the prefix `some_string`.  Once it has found that entry, beyond that the index might not help.  But an index on `some_column` should give you some performance benefit here.

A condition where an index would *not* help would be the following:

```
WHERE mutable.some_column LIKE '%some_string';
```

In this case, the index is rendered mostly useless, because we have no idea with what prefix the column value should begin.